# DFP mobile ads meant for one app are showing in another app

Tags: android, ads, google-dfp

I have been using DFP to show ads on an app. Now I created new ad units for ads on another app, and found that both ads are showing the same creatives I uploaded.

I made sure that the Ad Units are different (they have the same network code for both apps, but different ad Unit name) in the form

```
/networkCode/adUnitName
```

The ad units, orders, line items, and creatives are separate, but for some reason same ads are being served on both the apps.

Wonder why?

Thanks!

Comment: There is another perplexing thing. If I put any random string after the network code, eg, /87918382/abcdef  DFP is still able to serve ads.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you're getting ads with a random string for the inventory identifier, this maybe DFP falling back to serving adX ads when its unable to match to a specified unit, But I'm not 100% sure on that.

To use a single account for multiple websites I will using create inventory units that are specific to each site, So for a leader unit at the top of the page I might have:

```
siteOne_leader_unit, [[728,90], [960,300]]
siteTwo_leader_unit, [[728,90], [960,300]]
```

Then I can target specific line items to each site without any crossover, You can still create a single order but target each line item to specific inventory units which could be on different sites and still track the performance separately

Hope this helps. It's the only way I've got it to work reliably.